# Wordpress-Displaying children template in a parent page

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently creating a website, with wordpress. 
In a page, I created a submenu, in php using datas from my phpmyadmin, and with the ID of the children pages, I'm displaying the different contents. But, In one of my children page, I have some php code so I created a template, but it doesn't work at all...

ANyone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? Be more specific, add some code... etc

Comment: Without relevant code, this question is completely unanswerable.